# Pac ssh manager on Ubuntu 14.04 does not work

Tags: 14.04, perl, ssh-agent, cpan

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. For ssh, I am using pac manger. It was working perfectly on Ubuntu 12.04 but after upgrading to 14.04 pac does not work. When I run it from the terminal it says:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Gnome2::Vte::Terminal" (perhaps you forgot to load "Gnome2::Vte::Terminal"?) at /opt/pac/lib/PACTerminal.pm line 501.
```

I try to install missed perl modules by typing:

```
$ cpan Gnome2::Vte::Terminal
```

But that says "This modue does not exist.".

What is the proper way to getting run it on ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the latest release(v4.5.5) and reinstalled it. Now I can login through ssh to any server.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it by forcing PAC to use my system library instead of the embedded one by removing all `Vte.so*` files from PAC:

```
find /opt/pac/ -name "Vte.so*" -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used this fix:

- Manually install gnome2::vte package

> wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/X/XA/XAOC/Gnome2-Vte-0.11.tar.gz
>   
>   (You need to install -dev packages in order to be able to compile the module)

- Modify PACTerminal.pm to include the use of Gnome2::vte

> use Gnome2::Vte;

Once these changes were made I was able to use again PAC with SSH.